# How do I left indent my equation inside the align*?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I would like to left align my equation..... The sample code is given below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \beta&=\frac{\lambda.D}{d}\\
       &=\frac{\beta.d}{\lambda}\\
       &=\frac{0.60 \times d}{5000 \times 10^{-8}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to flush only this align, you may do as follows. If you want to flush all equations in your document, you may use `\documentclass[fleqn]{article}`.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe} % for proof... 

\begin{document}
    \begin{flalign*}
    \beta&=\frac{\lambda.D}{d} & \\
    &=\frac{\beta.d}{\lambda} \\
    &=\frac{0.60 \times d}{5000 \times 10^{-8}}
    \end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you just want to indent one single line of your `align*`, you should do:

```
\begin{align*}
\MoveEqLeft[2]\beta = \frac{\lambda.D}{d} \\ % change this number to what you like
&=\frac{\beta.d}{\lambda} \\
&=\frac{0.60 \times d}{5000 \times 10^{-8}}
\end{align*}
```